# Can't open old Pages files

Tags: software-update, pages

I have older Pages files I need to open. I am running Mavericks and get the "This file is too old..." error that tells me to save the file with Pages 09. So I reinstalled Pages 09' at it won't even open without updates and the AppStore says there are no updates. My 09' instal is in the applications/iWork folder. How can I get these files open?

Answer (score 1):

I've posted a solution for all three iWork programs at this Ask Different question: [New version of Keynote won't open old versions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176409) .